# subrings A of the ring of power series k[[t]] with the condition (A : k[[t]]) $\neq${0} and k $\subset$ A

Tags: commutative-algebra, power-series

I would like to understand the structure of the subrings A of the ring of formal power series k[[t]] (where k is a field) which satisfy the condition (A : k[[t]]) $\neq$ {0} and k $\subset$ A. Are they of the form {a$\in$ k[[t]] | v(a)$\geq$ n} + k ?

v is the order of the formal power series and (A : k[[t]]) = {a $\in$ k[[t]] | a k[[t]] $\subset$ A}.
Would someone help me with that?

Comment: No, they are not. Consider the $k$-algebra $k \oplus t^2.k \oplus t^4.k[[t]]$.

Comment: what do you mean? the power series with only even powers? it doesn't satisfy (A : k[[t]]) $\neq$ {0}

Comment: No, I mean powers series with powers greater than $4$ or equal to $2$ or $0$. This contains every power series with valuation greater than $4$.